# Copy-Item : Buffer cannot be null

Tags: powershell

This is my script. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

```
$listservers = Get-Content "C:\Users\bob\Documents\PowerShell\serverlist.txt"

$cred = Get-Credential
$source = "C:\PerfLogs\Admin\*"
$des = "C:\Users\bob\Documents\PowerShell\Logs\"

foreach($server in $listservers)
{
    
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Quiet)
    {
        $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred

        $final = "$des/$server"
        
        Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $final -FromSession $session -Recurse -Force -Verbose
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Unable to connect to" + $server
    }
  }
```

Copy-Item : Buffer cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer
At C:\Users\bob\Documents\PowerShell\copyEVLogs.ps1:17 char:9

- ```
      Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $final -FromSession $ses ...
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], ArgumentNullExcepti
    on
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentNullException,WriteException

Comment: Why are you appending a server name to a file path? ```$final = "$des/$server"```.  That's not a valid/proper UNC target.

Comment: Adding to Postanote's point, please understand that your variables are local to the script and it wont go inside the PSSession. Use Invoke-Command in this case and also pass the variables as param .. The logic has to be revisited.

Comment: Because I'm copying same file (perf.blg) from multiple servers to my computer. So I create folder on my computer with name of the server and copy the perf.blg file into it.

Comment: Postanote & Ranadip Dutta, thank you for your input. The issue was not my logic but rather it's the file types (perf.blg) that is causing the issue. I tested my script again but instead of copying .blg file. I copied .htmls, .csv, .txt, etc... and it works just fine.